# How can I solve this problem without using lists?

Tags: python

Problem: You're a swimmer, and you want to compare all of your race times to find the fastest one. Write a program that continuously takes race times as doubles from standard input, until the input is "no more races," at which point it should print out the time of your fastest race.

The answer I found on another thread was using lists like:

```
list1 = []
race_time = input("Enter a race time or type no more races to quit: ")
while race_time != "no more races":
    list1.append(float(race_time))
    race_time = input("Enter a race time or type no more races to quit ")
print(min(list1))
```

The problem is from if-else, and loops chapter and lists aren't introduced to us yet. How would I store the race times and compare them?

Comment: You could do a lot of things: use a dictionary, read from a file etc. However if you say you haven't used lists yet I doubt you would use them. The general route most people would take would to use lists, I would assume (if you are using a book) that it is a question for people that like to read ahead.

Comment: @BSQL The question is not made any easier with dictionaries or files, and the straight forward solution does not involve lists. It just wants you to keep track of the lowest time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just store the best time that you've seen so far and whenever the new time is better overwrite the old one:

```
import math

best_time = math.inf
[... your code ...]
while ...:
    if race_time < best_time:
        best_time = race_time
```

Comment: not introduced to modules yet.

Comment: @Cruise5 you can substitute `best_time = math.inf` with `best_time = float('inf')`

Comment: @Cruise5 Alternatively you can set `best_time = None` initially and then check for `if best_time is None or race_time < best_time`. But I'd go with the suggestion of Andrej as well.

Comment: What is 'inf' ? We book has not introduced it so it doesn't expect to use that.

Comment: Given the structure of OP's current code, you can just assign `best_time = float(race_time)` after the first `input(..)` and start comparing after the second. Or just set `best_time=999999` and pretend that's infinite enough for this assignment

Comment: @thatotherguy Indeed, I thought already about using the walrus operator here so that's why I automatically came up with a special value for initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Without list, it will be a little bit difficult to store all races. But as you are only looking for the speedest race:

```
race_time = input("Enter a race  time or type no more races to quit: ")
best_time=float(race_time) 
while race_time != "no more races":
    race_time = input("Enter a race time or type no more races to quit ")
    if race_time != "no more races":
       race_time=float(race_time) 
        if race_time<best_time:
            best_time=race_time

print(best_time)
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the first `if race_time != "no more races"`?

Comment: Else you will raise an exception by trying to change some text in float